# How to remove whitespace and extend background to full screen in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a simple game, but the background won't extend to the edges of any of the displays (iPhone and iPad) so there's whitespace at the top and bottom. In landscape orientation there's even more whitespace for some reason. I haven't coded anything yet.

Here's how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTQzo.jpg

I have constraints added to all four sides of the Image View and them set to View and 0.

I have also tried unchecking "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" and "Safe Area Relative Margins" neither of which helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the constraint to safe area. Instead of pinning your view's edges to safe area, pin them to your superview.
Here is how your constraints may look

[image]

Select each one of your constraint(double click on it)

And change the following, i.e. from safe area to superview. Also update the constant and set to 0.

[image]

Hope that helps